# How to get the URL of an uploaded image in Cloudinary

Tags: cloudinary

How can I get the URL of an uploaded image in Cloudinary so that it can be saved in a database when the file is uploaded using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Cloudinary PHP SDK to perform the upload](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration#quick_example_file_upload) the response to the call to the Upload method of the SDK will contain the metadata of the newly-uploaded image

There's an example in the documentation here: 
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_and_video_upload#upload_response

```
Array
(
  [public_id] => c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0
  [version] => 1571218607
  [signature] => f8645b000be7d717599affc89a068157e4748276
  [width] => 864
  [height] => 576
  [format] => jpg
  [resource_type] => image
  [created_at] => 2017-06-23T13:59:18Z
  [bytes] => 120253
  [type] => upload
  [url] => http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1571218607/c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0.jpg
  [secure_url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1571218607/c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0.jpg
)
```

`url` and `secure_url` will return the original image, but in order to access derived versions of the image, you should also store `public_id`, `resource_type`, `type` `format`, `version` so you can track the asset correctly and pass the necessary values to `cl_image_tag()` or `cloudinary_url()` when using the images in your application.